# Merge results from two has_many into one ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a messaging system, where a MessageUser can send Messages to multiple MessageUsers. Hence, a MessageUser has these relations to Messages:

```
has_many :sent_messages, foreign_key: :from_user_id, class_name: 'Message'
has_many :message_recipients, foreign_key: :to_user_id
has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', through: :message_recipients, source: :message
```

I would really like to have a `has_many :messages` that will allow a MessageUser to get a relation to all Messages, whether he/she is a sender or a receiver. I need to keep the result as an ActiveRecord object, so that I don't have to load it all into memory, and can delegate sorting, filtering and pagination to the database.

Can this be done?

(For reference, a MessageRecipient is just a class to keep this relation to recipients. It only has a message_id and a to_user_id.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, SQL might not be my strongest suit, but let's give it a shot.

```
Message.joins(:message_recipients)
.where{ message_recipients.to_user_id == user_id | from_user_id == user_id }
```

Using [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) syntax to avoid SQL. Might not be complete, but something like this could work.

Comment: This is what I ended up using: `Message.joins(:message_recipients).where('message_recipients.to_user_id == :user_id OR from_user_id == :user_id', {user_id: id}).uniq`.  
Of course, this is completely derived from your answer, so thank you very much!